# how to slide out registration form to next in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, registration, contact-form, user-registration

I use a plugin for sign up that is Ultimate Member. I want to float this form, and use continue button for next field. Can anybody tell me how can I do this!

Comment: which plugin you are using?

Comment: @dipmala Ultimate Member plugin I am using for registration, login, log out. But I want to float it and make a continue button for next field.